# WPF Arched Text Around Radial Menu

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I'm creating a radial menu in WPF for Microsoft <strike>Surface</strike> Pixelsense. Right now I have multiple surface buttons making up the menu. They are arranged around the circle by rotating them about the center of the menu in even radian steps, this way the top of the text is always touching the circle. I want the text in the button to be curved the same amount as the circle making up the menu. This way they contour to the menu circle.

**How can I curve the text in multiple buttons to have the same curve amount as the circle making up the menu?**

Thanks,
Andrew